# IIS (C#) send file request to a request method

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've done this before but I don't remember how. There is a way in an IIS app (C#) where you can tell it to send all requests for a "file" off a specific url to a method. And that method can then set the "file" in the response.

It's a way to avoid writing temporary files to disk and instead hold them in memory, verify that the request for that file is from the authenticated user, and then put the file held in memory int he response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `FileResult` instead of an `ActionResult` from the controller (assuming ASP.NET MVC or Web API here); more specifically, you probably want a `FileStreamResult` with the data stored in a `MemoryStream` or `FileStream`; or a `FileContentResult` with a binary array.

```
public FileResult GetFile(...)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    // Assign the data here
    // ...

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "MyFile.dat",
    };
}
```